# How to store time shown by cftimer in a variable?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfml

I want to store the time taken by a code to execute in a coldfusion variable.
There is a tag called cftimer that displays the time taken by a code to execute.
Is there a way to store the time displayed by cftimer tag in a variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
<cfset var startTicks = GetTickCount() />
<!--- code to benchmark --->
<cfset var ticksTaken = GetTickCount() - startTicks />
```

for better control. Note that ticks are ms, and irrelevant unless diffing (the absolute value has no meaning).

Answer (score 5):

As Adam and MaxH have stated, you'll want to use `getTickCount()` to time a script.

getTickCount() isn't just for troubleshooting, you can do a lot of cool stuff with it. If you want you can also do this inside your `onRequest` function to time all of your scripts and react to a long script if needed.

```
<cffunction name = "onRequest">
  <cfargument name = "targetPage" ...>
  <cfset startTime = getTickCount()>
  <cfinclude template = "#arguments.targetPage#">
  <cfset processTime = getTickCount()-startTime>
  <cfif structKeyExists(url,"showTime")>
    <cfoutput>The page took #processTime# milliseconds to process</cfoutput>
  </cfif>
  <!--- you could also do other stuff like record processing times to a db or send alerts if processTime > somevalue --->
</cffunction>
```

I have one project that depends on a lot of external data which is subscribed to by the customer. I save all the processing times for the individual processes into a session structure so I can see if it's me or one of the 3rd party web services that are causing the slow down. If one of the web services bogs down I alert the customer so they can decide if they want to choose a different service.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, it would be tricky to do, and trying to take a square peg out of a round hole. However what you can easily use [`getTickCount()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd0.html) to take the... well... the tick count before and after the operation, and the difference between the two is your duration. Which you can then do with what you want.